# How to join/concatenate some set of columns with another or make loop of it?

Tags: python, pandas, join, concatenation, nan

So, here for example I have 2 columns as Column1a, Column1b, and another 3 columns as Column2a, Column2b, Column2c. I want to make an output column where there is an array of Column1a to Column2c (if present) as given below.
At least one from column 1 and 1 from column 2 must be present for the output.

```
Column1a Column1b  Column2a Column2b Column2c OUTPUT
 123A     QWER     ERTY     1256Y    234
 3456     89AS
 WERT              1234     9087
                   CVBT
```

OUTPUT should be as follows:

```
OUTPUT
["123A|ERTY","123A|1256Y","123A|234","QWER|ERTY","QWER|1256Y","QWER|234]
""
["WERT|1234","WERT|9087"]
""
```

Please help me with using the loop in such cases.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to your question:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# df=pd.read_excel('demo2.xlsx')

all_columns = list(df) # Creates list of all column headers
df[all_columns] = df[all_columns].astype(str)

from itertools import product
x=pd.DataFrame(list(product([0,1], [2,3,4])), columns=['l1', 'l2'])


for j in range(len(df)):
    full=[]
    if (((df.iloc[j,0]=="nan") & (df.iloc[j,1]=="nan")) | ((df.iloc[j,2]=="nan") & (df.iloc[j,3]=="nan") &(df.iloc[j,4]=="nan")) ):
        full.append("")
    else: 
            l=[]
            for k in range(len(x)):
                if (df.iloc[j,x.iloc[k,0]]!="nan"):
                    l1=df.iloc[j,x.iloc[k,0]]
                    if (df.iloc[j,x.iloc[k,1]]!="nan"):
                        l2=df.iloc[j,x.iloc[k,1]]
                        full.append(l1+"|"+l2)
    df.loc[j,"OUTPUT"]=full
```

Output looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Hello @Yashar I used this and getting this error.ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable.Could you help?